# Ignore part of route path

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

One of the routes in my Angular 6 application is defined as below -

```
{ path: 'product/:productId', component: ProductPageComponent }
```

Now, I want to handle URLs like `/product/BEV15733/Raw-Apple-Cider-Vinegar` with this (i.e. I want to ignore the third path segment). However, when navigating, Angular throws error like -

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'product/BEV15733/Raw-Apple-Cider-Vinegar'

Comment: Why do you want to ignore it? Why have it on the URL in that case? You can always create a second url param, `:productName`, and just do nothing with it I guess

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
{ path: 'product/:productId/:ignoreParam', component: ProductPageComponent }
```

With ':' you expect a param in your url, and you can ignore this last segment.